# How to prompt maximum resolution beyond 1080?

Tags: 20.04, 4k-monitor

Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a Gateway SX2370-UR30P.   Originally connected to a 1080p TV.  Now connected to a 4K monitor via HDMI.  Max resolution shows 1080.

What can be done to prompt / configure higher resolutions?

## xrandr

> [xrandr](https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/use-xrandr.html)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: Can you update your original question with the results of running `xrandr` in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If your machine has an AMD A6-3600 APU, you can't. 1080p is the max resolution supported. 4K didn't exist when this chip was created.